# Extjs4 how to remove duplicated rows from a grid?

Tags: grid, extjs4, filtering

`My_grid` contains many duplicated rows (same `name` and `username`, and with  different hidden `id`). How to remove duplicated rows?

Answer (score 3):

you should set the **idProperty** of your proxy's reader or on your model.

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/myUrl',
        reader: {
            idProperty: 'Id'
        }
    },
    model: 'myModel'
});
```

Comment: This helps, but when I set the **idProperty** of the store, the grid will be displayed filtered, but I want to filter it and remove duplicated rows when I click on a button! So can I change the value of the store's **idProperty**? I have tried `Ext.getCmp('My_grid').getStore().set(idProperty, 'Id')`, but that's wrong!

Comment: It seams store does not have a `set` method, furthermore the `idProperty` is a configuration for reader/model. you should do like the above example.

Comment: can I make a composed idProperty ? I mean tow values in the same idProperty

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works for you hopefully:

It's important that you declared your store and grid with this. 
For example `this.store = ...`

```
  //Listener on the button removes the duplicated rows
        this.button.on('click', function() {
            this.store.each(function(record) {
                //This is necessary because if this record was removed before
                if(record !== undefined) {
                    //Find all records which have the same name like this record
                    var records = record.store.query('name', record.get('name'));

                    //Remove all found records expect the first record 
                    records = records.each(function(item, index) {
                        //Don't delete the first record
                        if(index != 0) {
                            item.store.remove(item);    
                        }    
                    });    
                }
            }); 
        }, this);
```